# Telerik MVC treeview - dynamically added textbox - can't click to change cursor position

Tags: model-view-controller, treeview, tree, telerik

I have drag drop enabled and i know that is the cause of my problem. I am allowing the tree nodes to be editable and on edit i show a textbox, but when you click in it to change the cursor position, nothing happens.

if i disable drag/drop then it is not an issue. I have tried to stop the event from bubbling up by putting click event handler for the textbox and doing preventdefault, stopPropagation, returning false, but that doesn't work.

I have also disabled the li element but that doesnt help.

Some event handler is getting called and i cannot find out which one (i have set breakpoints in all event handlers in the telerik.treeview.js but none are called when i click inside the textbox.

anybody have any idea?